# Is there a database tool that will automatically move Dropbox folders after a user presses a button?

Tags: database, file-management, dropbox

I work at a smaller company. We are currently using Dropbox to manage project folders. One person will create drawings and place them in a folder. Another will check them, sign on the PDF of the drawing, and place into a different folder. Another user will do the same, until there's a final resting place for them, a completed folder we have.

Problem is that if you are trying to look for a specific project, you might have to click through a few different folders until you find what you are looking for. And, some of the users are pretty bad at cutting and pasting one folder to a different location.

I was trying to see if there was some way of having a database that lists where folders are located, maybe evening having a hyperlink to them, e.g. I look for project *X* in this database, and am able to get pointed to its spot in Dropbox.

If a user checks a drawing, maybe they could also press a button (via macro, something) in the database that would automatically move the folder to the next location to be checked and update the hyperlink.

Comment: Would you also consider a different approach, such as proper [project-management](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) software – where you e.g. attach files to a ticket, and set the status correspondingly? No different folders required then, and you know work is completed if the status is set to "completed". You even can assign the ticket to a person (or group) who's job is due, so e.g. when the drawings are finished the ticket is assigned to the PDF group etc.

Comment: I removed the [tag:microsoft-excel] tag because the solution didn’t seem to be required to work with Excel. If it is required, please add it again and explain in the question in which way. -- And: Does this mean you need a solution for Windows?

Comment: Maybe not project-management per se, but document-management software will do.

Comment: A solution for Windows, please. I can look into project management software. I was hired on the very tail end of them making the decision to use Dropbox. I believe whatever they were looking at (PLM software) was quite expensive.